# Laravel Dynamic Header

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel. I include Header using @include('header'). but I want to hide profile menu when user is not register. How can I do ?
I use this to get data from table directly in  blade.php

```
$array = App\Table::Select(users)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Auth` facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated) to determine if the current user is logged in:

header.blade.php

```
@if(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
    <!-- profile menu -->
@endif
```

###### Edit: You can use blade directives except the `@if` to checking user is authenticated or not. like the following:

```
@auth
    <!-- Profile Menu -->
@endauth
```

If you—for whatever reason— just want to know if some user is registered, change your query to the following:

```
@if(Profile::find($userId) !== null)
    <!-- profile menu -->
@endif
```

Comment: but I want to get data from profile table.

Comment: I don't see the use case but be my guest - I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `auth` facade for this.

`@auth // The user is authenticated... @endauth`

`@guest // The user is not authenticated... @endguest`

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this

```
   if(Auth::user())
      include('header')
   endif
```